# How to prevent 'sudo rm -rf /'

Tags: terminal, bash, sudo

A few times I have accidentally executed the command `sudo rm -rf /`.

Is there a way how to prevent me from running this command? For example can I somehow disable it using the sudoers file?

Comment: How do you accidentally type this command and then execute it??

Comment: If I type in a command like this. `sudo rm -rf / Applications/chess.app` Notice the space between the / and the A. That's how

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a line like

```
%admin ALL = !/bin/rm -rf /
```

to your `sudoers` file to prevent the execution of the command with the specific options.

Or, if you want to exclude several commands, you can work with command aliases

```
Cmnd_Alias DANGEROUS_CMNDS=/bin/rm -rf /, /bin/rm -fr /
%admin ALL=!DANGEROUS_CMNDS
```

You can also try to play it safe by using

```
Cmnd_Alias DANGEROUS_CMNDS=/bin/rm -rf /, /bin/rm -fr /, /bin/rm / *, /bin/rm * /, /bin/rm -rf / *, /bin/rm -rf * /, /bin/rm -fr / *, /bin/rm -fr* /
%admin ALL=!DANGEROUS_CMNDS
```

but there still might be other ways you can shoot yourself in the foot with `rm` so *be careful* anyway.

But keep in mind that all matching is done on the full string of the command, so `sudo rm -rf /Volumes` would still work (as would `cd /; sudo rm -rf .`).

PS: By all means, use `sudo visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file and **NEVER** edit it directly

PPS: I obviously didn't test this with `rm` (only with `/bin/echo` instead)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24887/discussion-on-answer-by-patrix-how-to-prevent-sudo-rm-rf).

Answer (score 6):

I know you phrased the question in a way that makes me suspect you don't want to hear this answer, but you really should remove yourself from the sudoers file if you're prone to making the same mistake over and over.

The underlying problem is you haven't aliased `rm` to be move to trash (which is clearly how you are using it currently and in the past) or otherwise forced `rm -r` to be forced into `rm -ri`

```
alias rm='/bin/rm -i'
```

You can always get around the alias with `command rm -rf whatever` once you've trained your mind on when measure twice, cut once is needed for `rm -rf` use.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I was thinking on making am hidden admin account (to access terminal only) and a standard account for normal use only. I could make the wrapper to move to the trash instead too. Thanks for that tip. I think that preventing sudo may be a safer step. I will still make sure I can access it by logging into the hidden admin.

Comment: Haven't marked is a s answered though since it doesn't answer the above. This is still good advice though